# docker host network container in host network

Tags: docker, networking, virtualization

my task is to place a docker container on the network of the parent system, and put a neighboring ip address. Roughly speaking, make a second virtual machine with your own mac address and your own ip address. Unfortunately, I've tried everything already .. pipework does not correctly throw the physical interface inside the container, makvlan does not give access to the Internet ... I tried host mode in the docker's network, but it gives two ip addresses to the container (one address of the parent system, the second address of the second physical interface . Tell me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `docker run -p` option to publish a port (accept inbound connections) on a specific interface.  Say the host network is 192.168.1.0/24, the primary address is 192.168.1.111, and the second address is 192.168.1.222; then you can

```
docker run -p 192.168.1.222:80:5000
```

and port 80, on the host, only on the secondary interface, will get forwarded to port 5000 in the container.  The default for this IP address is 0.0.0.0, making the port accessible on all interfaces.

You need to configure the secondary IP address on the host.  Installing Docker on the system doesn't change the mechanics of this at all.

You do not need host networking: it generally disables Docker networking, and in this example it means the container process gets to see all the host interfaces, so the *process* would need to be configured to bind to the right interface.  Conversely, using standard networking, you need to make sure the process binds to the 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address, as is typical in Docker.

Comment: I must have all ports open. How to host